# Fragment Navigation between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, fragment

I'am new in Android and I work with fragments. I have activity (MainActivity) and 3 Fragments, A->B->C. I need to back navigate from C fragment to B, from B to A and backward. I was cliked on Fragment A see A, clicked on B see B, clicked on C see C, but when I clicked Back my app was closed. Why ?
Here is a example what I call fragments

```
Fragment Subcategory = new Subcategory();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("id", i);
            String title = dba.getTitle(i,true);
            bundle.putString("title", title);
            Subcategory.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentTransaction transaction_cat = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            transaction_cat.replace(R.id.fragment_container, Subcategory);
            transaction_cat.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction_cat.commit();
```

I can't found any simple example which show me how to navigate between fragments, and after reading [this article](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html) I don't understand how it works.
Tell me please, and write example how I must do this.

Comment: When you mention you would like to back navigate, is that programmatically or via the back button?

Comment: Back button, it means hardware button on smartphone.

Comment: Dont't know if there is a difference, but...you could add a name to the FragmentTransaction: `transaction_cat.addToBackStack("subcategory");`

Comment: I think it just add custom tag, it is not important, i can use FragmentTransaction without TAG, isn't it?

Comment: did you override onBackPressed in your activity ?

Comment: @streamride I hust have this method in MainActivity with empty body.

Comment: try to call super.onBackPressed() in your onBackPressed()

Comment: @streamride when I was called it my app was closed. ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try override method `onBackPressed()` for the activity.

update:

Here is part of my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    RelativeLayout mContainer;

    int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
        addFragment();
    }

    private void addFragment() {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        Fragment f = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        if (f == null) {
            f = new MainActivityFragment();
            f.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, f);
            ft.addToBackStack("" + count++);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }

    private void replaceFrament() {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        Fragment f;
        f = new BlankFragment();
        f.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, f);
        ft.addToBackStack("" + count++);
        ft.commit();
    }

    public void onAddFragmentClick(View v) {
        replaceFrament();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".MainActivityFragment">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Fragment"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:onClick="onAddFragmentClick"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, always when I press Back button, the onBackPressed() method calls, but **how I can find in onBackPressed** what fragment I need to load ? by tag in **addToBackStack("Tag")**?

Comment: addToBackStack("Tag") should be used when you create the fragment. Your code seems correct. Did you try `transaction_cat.replace(R.id.fragment_container, Subcategory).addToBackStack(null).commit();`?

Comment: Actually, you don't need to override onBackPressed() in your activity. onBackPressed from super class will handle it correctly.

Comment: what's the difference between `transaction_cat.replace(R.id.fragment_container, Subcategory);
            transaction_cat.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction_cat.commit();`
and your code ?
`transaction_cat.replace(R.id.fragment_container, Subcategory).addToBackStack(null).commit();`

Comment: Theoretically, there is some difference between the 2 snips of code. But in this case there is no.